# set token price solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

how can I set the price of each token in solidity?

I've tried

```
contract OToken {

using SafeMath for uint256;

uint public _totalSupply = 0;
uint public constant _cap = 100000000;
string public constant symbol = "OXN";
string public constant name = "OToken";
uint public constant decimals = 18;

uint public oneTokenInWei = 183.602;
```

If I want the token price to be $0.02 each and 1 eth is trading at $167
then 1 wei = 183.602 tokens

I can call this function if I want to change the price per token to .03

```
 function setOneTokenInWei(uint w) onlyOwner {
    oneTokenInWei = w;
    changed(msg.sender);
}
```

then this function to create the token

```
function createTokens() payable{

    require(
        msg.value > 0
        && _totalSupply < _cap
        && CROWDSALE_PAUSED <1
        );

        uint multiplier = 10 ** decimals;
        uint256 tokens = msg.value.mul(multiplier) / oneTokenInWei;

        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

this is not adding the current value to the senders wallet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We know that 1 Ether = 10<sup>18</sup> wei, if we take that 1 Ether = $ 167

Then for $ 0.02 we should get $ 0.02 / $ 167 = 0.00011976047904191617 Ethers.

This equals to 10<sup>18</sup> x 0.00011976047904191617 = 119760479041916.17 wei.

So if you put 1 Ether you will get 10<sup>18</sup> / 119760479041916.17 = 8350 tokens.

At the price of $ 167 each token value is 167 / 8350 = 0.02 as desired.

I'd define a function so you can set the price of one ether and it derive the price of one token at two cents.

```
function setEthPrice(uint _etherPrice) onlyOwner {
    oneTokenInWei = 1 ether * 2 / _etherPrice / 100;
    changed(msg.sender);
}
```

Comment: the _etherPrice argument's price is in dollar or eth ? for instance:  I have a token price of 10 cents and 1 ETH is 432 dollar as of now..So  1 ether * 10 / (432 or 1 ether) / 100.. is it accurate?? it's giving me wrong result...

Comment: @Yash You have to apply the [cross multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication). For a 0.10 $ token at 1ether = 432$ it costs `10**18 * 10 / 432 / 100 =  231481481481481` wei. For 1 ether you get `10**18 / 231481481481481 = 4320` tokens, which is reasonable.

Comment: Thank you for replying..I want to know is there any alternate formula for finding the price of one token in solidity without actually specifying the ether price in dollar...For instance, I want to issue token based on ethereum input 0.023 which is 10 dollar. So what I want is to issue token as much as the ETH received without specifying the ethereum price in dollar...Something like ethereumToToken and tokenToEthereum function

Comment: @Yash It is a completely different question. You want to obtain the ether price in USD, for that you have to use an oracle, for example MakerDao's Medianizer. Search here or on ethereum.stackexchange.com there should be examples how to use it.